# How can I insert a while loop inside a for loop on Matlab without having to manually stop the run?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, while-loop

So I am using a while loop inside a for loop to stop the iteration at the condition written next to "while" in the code shown in the link below:

[Matlab Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU2eu.png)

The run is not ending on Matlab but when I pause the run, I see right answers for h1 & h2 & h3 & h4. I just need the run to end by itself without having me to impose the stop. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: We prefer it if you enter the code rather than linking to a screenshot.

Comment: Also, you have parameters in the code like h12, h21, etc. that are not defined, so we cannot run the code for ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

The run is most likely not ending because the condition of your `while` statement is always true, so it never exits the while loop. You are probably best off investigating why this is the case, but alternatively you can use Matlab's [break](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html) command to force an exit from the while loop.